# How do I decode the following JSON?

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON object of the format

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
          "title": "Juliette DELAUNAY",
          "author:url": "abc.com"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

To decode in my go program, I have made the following structs

```
type results struct{
    Result []result `json:"results"`
}

type result struct{
    Hits []hit `json:"hits"`
}

type hit struct{
    Name string `json:"title"`
    Url string `json:"author:url"`
}
var m =make(map[string]string)
var t results
```

But when I try to do the following,

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)


    err = decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }


    for _,x := range t.Result[0].Hits{
        m[x.Name] = x.Url
        fmt.Println(x.Name,x.Url)
    }
```

It gives a runtime error saying index is out of range. What am I doing wrong? Are my structs incorrect for the given json?

EDIT : The JSON file I need to decode

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"requests":[{"indexName":"recherchepepitesAtoZ","params":"query=x&hitsPerPage=2817&maxValuesPerFacet=42&page=0&facets=%5B%22field_frenchtech_hub_pepite%22%2C%22field_categorie%22%2C%22field_frenchtech_hub_pepite%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://6y0slgl8yj-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.20.4%3Binstantsearch.js%201.10.4%3BJS%20Helper%202.18.0&x-algolia-application-id=6Y0SLGL8YJ&x-algolia-api-key=6832a361e1e1628f8ddb2483623104c6", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    //req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: please let me know if you see a silly mistake. I have been at it for hours and I am really frustrated now and I cant see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Provided snippet works normally on my machine without any errors

Comment: i have added the json file I am trying to decode. Is it working for it?

Comment: what is `m` in `m[x.Name] = x.Url`? the provided example is correct, check carefully where `index is out of range` error is reported

Comment: I forgot to mention, `var m =make(map[string]string)` is a global variable

Comment: I checked, it is for t.Result[0] . When I do a `fmt.Println(t.Result)` it outputs `[]`

Comment: t should be []Result ?

Comment: @Krash Sorry I'm too lazy to do POST requests for you. But as of code works with test JSON, I think URL just provide invalid JSON or you have mistakes in other places. Your structure works fine for JSON you show.

Comment: @Krash Do you happen to read resp.body before calling decode?

Comment: @Uvelichitel Ok, What I tried was store the response body in a string and then try `json.Decode` like Niko does in his answer below. It worked that way. Any idea why it works this way but not the other way around?

Comment: @Gonfva Yes, I was reading `resp.Body` . Does that mess it up ?

Comment: Just learning go myself, but I guess it consumes the buffer and when you try to decode, the buffer is empty

Comment: @Gonfva Wow thanks. It works now. I am sorry for taking everyone's time. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version that works on my machine and go playground:

[GoPlayground](https://play.golang.org/p/UuDjBO-Gun)

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

type results struct {
  Result []result `json:"results"`
}

type result struct {
  Hits []hit `json:"hits"`
}

type hit struct {
  Name string `json:"title"`
  Url  string `json:"author:url"`
}

var m = make(map[string]string)

func main() {
  jsonSample := `{
  "results": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
          "title": "Juliette DELAUNAY",
          "author:url": "abc.com"
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
  }`

  var t results
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonSample))

  err := decoder.Decode(&t)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  for _, x := range t.Result[0].Hits {
    m[x.Name] = x.Url
    fmt.Println(x.Name, x.Url)
  }
}
```